# Jira workflow export does not contains transition properties

Tags: import, export, workflow, jira, transition

I have exported workflows from the test instance of Jira. Then I imported those workflows to another instance. However the imported workflows does not contain the original transition properties (Conditions, Validators, Post Functions).

How to export-import workflows including transitions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you exporting "as XML" or "as Workflow"?

"As Workflow" supports only native JIRA conditions and post-functions. Everything that is delivered by 3rd party plugins are not supported.

Typically 2nd step of "as Workflow" export wizard reports about incompatible elements like :

> The items from the following plugins were removed from the workflow:
>
> Transition: Open
>
> System post functions removed from this transition:
>    Update Issue Field
>
> Transition: In Progress
>
> System post functions removed from this transition:
>    Update Issue Field